# Add_after paragraph in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am not sure if I've been missing anything obvious, but I have not found anything documented about inserting the text after a certain word is detected.
i am trying to populate a docx CV template and i have the data. So when the heading(word) "Languages" is detected i want the data to be copy under it. i have used para.text = para.text+'\n'+my_data but the data is copied in the style of paragraph.

I am stuck in this part of my work and haven't found anything relevant to it yet.
If any body is can help me that would be great.

[Things i want to achieve vs what i am able to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZXEL.png)

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to follow. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you search Google on "python-docx insert_paragraph_after" you'll find several resources on this. Probably best to start there.

Comment: @scanny well i found a way around. But now i am stuck at getting the text of previous paragraph suppose if a table is detected i want to know it's heading

Comment: Better follow @NicholasTJ 's advice and add a minimal code example and be very specific about what you are unable to do.